# How to deny customer to change email adress

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, email

I am using Magento 1,9
I am making a b2b store and I would like to deny customer from changing email adress at any time, so this can only be done in backend

And easy solutions?

Answer (score 0):

***Magento 1*** has default checker to check mail address is changed or not.

```
$customer->getIsChangeEmail()
```

Here ***$customer*** is coming from the session, you can check it from the file location.
***app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php***

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to edit the template files involved in screens such as /customer/account/edit/ and just remove the field.

Turn off guest checkout and that should be that.

System > Configuration > Sales > Checkout

- Allow Guest Checkout - set it to No
- Require Customer To Be Logged in To Checkout - set it to Yes

Comment: Perfect, it works. Do you know how I remove first name and last name as well?